# Database design with loop

Tags: database-design

The database I'm currently building is pretty complicated to me. So it would be much more complicate if i try to explain so i will try to generalize. The question is at the end of the post.

So I created a little database model. The Tables are connected with a n:m relationship. Only the manufacturer and the machine tables have a 1:n relationship to machine_manufacturer.
[image: ER-Diagram]

The table PlanForMakeACar holds information about to build a car and has a relationship to the table "measurementData" which holds created data while the production process.

The table "machine_manufacturing" just holds the information for the group "manufactures" which machines do they have for production.

Is that okay or do i miss something to avoid the loop? 
My researches showed me the following contribution: 
[Why sould I avoid loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115748/why-should-i-avoid-loops-when-designing-relationships-for-a-database)

Comment: I don't really see a loop here, more like wrong links between tables. For example between car and manufacturer at manufacturers side.

Comment: Ah, okay my bad this was not a perfect example.

I need this relationship to declare that a manufacturer has N cars.
And a car (in this example) could have more manufacturer.

The "manufacture" table is basically only a filter table for the car table with the information about the manufactures machines.

Comment: Does the `manufacturer` build `cars`, or does it build `machine`s that build `cars`?

Comment: The manufactures is, like i try to said before, only a filter table. 
But in this example he would build cars and for that he has a filtered list of machines.

In the front end the steps are
1, Create a manufacture with his machines.
2. Create a car with his manufacturegroup. 
Now lay it to the database.

At some point another program comes and take the data out of the database and want to create a "real" car. Now the program checks: oh with what machine can i produce it (he gets a list out of the manufactue table connection to machines).

Comment: Sorry need an extra comment but it stuck to the comment before.

Now the production of the car begins and the data have to been written in the database. Therefore the table measurementData and the connection to the machine table because i didn't know before which machine produced the data.

You need to see it separated maybe?

Comment: What is a filter table anyway?  Is manufacturer an entity or not? Databases have no "filters", they have tables and relationships. Every time you say X is a "filter table" you make your point less clear,. Also ER diagrams have no "start point". Also much of the question is "lost in translation".

Comment: I deleted unnecessary information in the original question. Hope its clearer now.

Comment: **You need to [edit] your question and describe the real world situation - first**. After all, your database design is only a model of the real world. There is too much commenting going on because you are not clear **what you want to accomplish**.

Answer (score 2):

Loops are not in themselves a sign of a modelling problem, and I think the other question that you reference demonstrates that quite well.

It may help to think of "context" for joins, which is the concept that the business situations in which different potential joins apply express different business contexts.

For example, a person can be "connected" with a car manufacturer because she owns a car built by them. She might also be connected because she subscribes to an email bulletin from them. She might also be employed by them.

Three different contexts, and while it is conceivable that two contexts might be invoked by a query ("find all Honda owners who are not subscribed to their email bulletins"), the more usual query is going to be within one particular context, and hence not involve "loops" in the query.

I'm not aware that this concept of the "context" is in any way a formal approach to analysis, although I wouldn't rule it out, but it may be helpful to consider it.